TCP server in C and `while(1)` to keep listening
I would like to create a simple example TCP server in C. It should be able to receive multiple client connections and to send a string to each of them separately, before closing the connection.
Many code samples like this one use a while(1) loop to keep listening for incoming client connections. Even in Richard Stevens - Unix Network Programming, Volume 1, Third Edition, Section 5.2, Figure 5.2 it is used for ( ; ; ), so almost the same.
This is probably the simplest solution, but is it correct from the programmer's perspective? Aren't such loops somewhat discouraged?
As an alternative, at least a SIGKILL could be catched instead and used as a condition for while, instead of 1. However, this is somewhat not the first advice in the answers to this question.
The actual question: is there any solution other than while(1) in this case? Is there a standard one, or does it depend on the specific program? In my case, I would like to keep it as simple as possible, but I would also like to avoid while(1).

Listening socket typically use select to wait until a relevant activity in the socket happens, and so CPU overload is not an issue at all.

The loop presumably includes an accept() that will suspend the process until a new connection is made.

@Shawn .. unless the socket is open as non-blocking. For whatever reason

Fwiw, the example you linked to uses semaphores which isn't needed. Just use atomic variables or mutexes to synchronize threads.

I suggest a copy of W. Richard Stevens' classic book Unix Network Programming, or Beej's Guide instead of the notoriously low quality geeksforgeeks site if you want to learn sockets.

@Shawn Thank you so much for these suggestions. At least Stevens also uses a for ( ; ; ) loop and I still wonder if there are alternatives to this approach.

"Aren't such loops somewhat discouraged?" What could you use instead, if you want to repeat forever?

The only real alternative is to use a super-server, like inetd, that does the listening and starts new server processes when a connection comes in. This works well when you don't need any communication between all the servers.

Is there any solution to what? If you want your program to continue accepting connections indefinitely then while (1) or an equivalent is exactly what provides such behavior.  On the other hand, if you want there to be a termination condition other than the program being externally killed, then what condition you want to use is an essential component of the problem to be solved, which you have not disclosed.

SIGKILL cannot be caught or blocked.  Perhaps you were thinking of SIGTERM, but the only reason to intercept SIGTERM and then proceed to terminate is if you want to interpose some kind of shutdown procedure.  Otherwise, it's much easier to just use SIGTERM's default disposition, which is already to terminate the program.

Event-loops are not discouraged; to the contrary, they are standard practice.  What is discouraged is busy-looping, i.e. trying an operation over and over again forever without ever waiting for I/O.  That's bad, because it wastes CPU power (and on a machine that runs on battery, it wastes battery charge).  Unless your program is doing nothing but computation, it's important that somewhere in your event-loop you call a function that blocks until more I/O is ready to be handled, otherwise your program will be very inefficient.

Without a loop (while (1), for (;;) or any other form) you can implement only a "one-shot" server which can accept only single connection, handle it and exit. If you want to handle multiple connections (not even simultaneous but sequential) and you don't know number of connections in advance, you need some form of loop.

Answering to The actual question: you can avoid while (1) and keep accepting multiple connections using recursion:
void handle_next_connection(int server)
{
   int client = accept(server, ...);
   recv(client, ...);
   send(client, ...);
   close(client);

   handle_next_connection(server);
}

int main(void)
{
    int server = socket(...);
    bind(server, ...);
    listen(server, ...);

    handle_next_connection(server);

    close(server);

    return 0;
}

If your compiler optimizes tail recursion into loop, you won't get a stack overflow.

If you are asking "does this work", the answer is yes.
Yoou need a program that "launches", opens a listener and keeps going. If you didn't have the loop, I assume you'd end up just answering once, and then having to quit? That probably is not what you want.
If a server is "something that listens forever and responds to requests", the answer is "sort of".
Ideally you could write a simple app that doesn't have major bugs or leaks, bugs, but even then, the server (as a listener) would probably eventually crash, because the OS might have underlying leaks.
Like, would you write a server that does no logging? Proabably not. Would you put it on a server with infinite disk space, probably not.
Uptime is built on taking a program (code) and keeping in active processes (running instances) [borrowing from terminology from Xinu].
So, overtime, many extra layers were added that would surround your program like:

running many copies in parallel
having a system process make sure inbound connection requests are sent to a process (inetd was mentioned in the comments)
having a watchdog process check on the process and restart them if they died.
using various network layer solutions (load balancing, multiple DNS records, etc).

(and all of this is just at the classic server + IPv4 era, "cloud computing" takes it to another architectural level)
